# AS3 clock alarm help~

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, clock, alarm

I made a clock in Actionscript3.
It has no alarm and I want to try making one.
How do you make an alarm that alarms after 5min, 10min, 1hr?

Comment: Well instead of adding useless text, maybe you could actually make the question higher quality? Such as showing what you have tried, and showing your specific problem, with a code example perhaps? -1, voted to close

Comment: Rule #1 of programming: Write your own code. We can help with specific questions, especially if you have some of your own code in your question, but we won't write your code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Actionscript3 API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html).  Basically, you make a Date object when the user creates the alarm and store its hours, minutes, etc. in a local variable. Then, you check with a timer whether or not the current Date's hour/minute/whatever matches the local variable's value plus whatever the delay is.